# How to understand that SOAP webservice use HTTP only for transport?

Tags: web-services, rest, http, soap, web

As I understand RESTful webservices use whole power of http, suffice to say all that rest need is http, but in the same time rest!=http. CRUD provides ability to do any action with API resourses, for example we send http request, this request has header for aunthefication, name of method (for example put), and json in body for updating. How this proces is running via SOAP? SOAP uses XML, but how this XML is delivered to API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOAP is based on XML and it conveys that messages are delivered in a SOAP envelope that has a header and a body.

[image: SOAP envelope]

When a SOAP message (be it a request or response) is delivered over HTTP you will have the whole envelope put in the HTTP body.

[image]

If the implementation is proper, in the HTTP header, in `Content-Type` you will have `application/soap+xml`.

Also in SOAP 1.1 you might have the `SOAPAction` header, which is not mandatory and is discussed in detail [in this article](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/unraveling_the_mystery_of_soap.html#__federated=1).

See [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_soap_example.asp) for sample raw SOAP request and response. Here is an [intro to SOAP](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/an-introduction-to-the-simple-object-access-protocol-soap/) that you might also find helpful.

Hope this helps! Good luck.

Comment: Thx, u clarify an important moment to me, it's that soap envelop is also transported in http body. Great.
So I have another question,  what kind of http method is used when request is sended to soap server? And according to this pictures u have been attached there are http header, does it mean that for (for example) authefication in soap is based also on http headers just like in rest?

Comment: POST is used for requests. And for authentication you can have both HTTP basic authentication or something more sophisticated, supported by SOAP like WS-Security.

Comment: And one more) If soap is not used http for authentification how server will accept this request? Think server should parse xml envelop and find token ther? Am i right?

Comment: Generally Yes, but I guess it depends on the alternative method you're using. I haven't got into detail for all available options for authentication with SOAP. You can start by investigating WS-Security use cases for authentication.